# Locate Cause of IBM DB2 CAST Failure

Tags: sql, db2

I need to work on an IBM DB2 database.

The `LOCATION` field is a `CHARACTER(8)` field of numbers.

To sort the table, the column is cast to an `INTEGER`:

```
SELECT LOCATION, PARTNO, INSTOCK 
FROM INVENTORY
ORDER BY CAST(LOCATION AS INTEGER)
```

Currently, this fails with:

> ERROR [22018] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0420N Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "INTEGER".

Is there a quick way to determine which row is failing?

[IBM's solution](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21367400) is to *"Insure that the results set for the query item that the cast it being applied to does not contain non numeric SQL constants when casting to a numeric type."*

That wasn't really helpful.

Thinking someone inserted a letter O or lower case L, I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION 
FROM LOCATIONS 
WHERE LOCATION LIKE '%l%' OR LOCATION LIKE '%O%'
ORDER BY LOCATION
```

Zero records returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That wasn't really helpful.

That's IBM error messages and documentation in a nutshell.

One place to start is the [`TRANSLATE()` function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-164).

```
SELECT LOCATION, PARTNO, INSTOCK 
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE TRANSLATE(LOCATION, '', ' 0123456789') <> ''
```

You can add other characters, like `-`, `.`, etc. depending on what you find.

Comment: Spaces and dots would also cause problems when cast to `INTEGER`, so the function call should really look like `TRANSLATE(LOCATION, '', '0123456789')`

Comment: @mustaccio Not necessarily. `' 123'` and `'1234   '` cast to `INTEGER` just fine.  So would `'+11'` and `'-11'`, but not `'11-'`.  This will help him find most of the problematic fields, but it won't necessarily find all of them and may miss some.  About the only thing the above misses is `'123    456'`.  I don't remember if `'11.'`  works or not in DB2.  The point was that he can easily change the characters to strip out more if he needs to.

Comment: That was it, Bacon Bits. Some developer had stuck `Cart003`, `test`, `Stage01`, etc. in there. I appreciate the help. I didn't even know about a [TRANSLATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-164) function.

Comment: But `'12 34'` does not, so you may want to account for that. Or may be you don't.